# Django model phone field

Tags: python, django, django-models

The contents of models.py for books app.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, unique=True, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{10}$', message='Length has to be 10', code='Invalid number')])
    # phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here in the Author class, I want the phone numbers to accept only digits with length 10. I would have used an IntegerField if it had a min_length attribute.

Now, here is what I tried in the django shell

```
>>> from books.models import *
>>> p = Author(name='foo', email='foo@bar.com', phone='962027')
>>> p.save()
>>>
```

For this, shouldn't it raise an error saying the phone field is not valid(since it does not have 10 digits)?

I checked the table books_author and that row got added.

What did I do wrong here? Please help.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. But notice that you specified the `max_length`, the biggest length the field could have, and a value like `962027` doesn't break this rule.

Comment: But it does break the RegexValidator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation about [how validators are run](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run), in particular:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model

You need to validate using a form, or call `p.full_clean()` explicitly.

Comment: You mean I need to call p.full_clean() after I create the object?